# How can I reduce spam posted via a simple comment / review system?

Tags: php, regex

I know there is hundreds examples of the question I'm about to ask. But none of them was working for me like a wanted.

So, I have a textarea, in which people can add comments/ reviews. But the commenting box keeps getting spammed.

I guess the regular expression might be the most efficient way to keep spammers out, but I stink at Regex.

Is there any other way to keep the spam out?

Edit: the spammers keep posting something like that:

> Brianna
>     Looking for work Lolita Pics it would of been better if she was fucking in front of the      mirror! 
>     its more sexy seeing yourself getting f#@$. 
>     just getting horny thinking about it
>     Preteens Nn Models omg if that

(spoilered, lightly censored to avoid causing folks problems at work)

So i want to block per hyperlink in string

Comment: How about using captcha?

Comment: Trying to do it without captcha :)

Comment: some kind of confirmation is needed, you have to make sure it's a human being paying attention. So captcha or some other mechanism that shows the reader read your post. You could also tell them to use a certain 'keyword' in the comment and scan for that. Or you can block spammers by IP. Regexing the content of the comment would be very difficult, cause now they're spamming Lolita, but tomorrow Warez.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to get rid of spam:

1. **Captcha** - for example [ReCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha), but nowadays you can buy about ~1000 rewritten captcha for less than 3$.
2. **Questions in your language about the most known facts** - you can ask your users about some facts that they know, but spammers don't.
3. **Antispam filters** - for example [Sblam!](http://sblam.com/en.html), [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) or other anti-spam services. I think it would work best for you.

Comment: I think captcha is a good idea too, it doesn't even need to be text based: http://www.script-tutorials.com/top10-really-user-friendly-captchas/

Comment: They aren't user friendly, because the user have to do something.. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/04/in-search-of-the-perfect-captcha/

Comment: I also wrote about antispam filters, it's the best solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Alot of Captcha is now bot solvable, and if you're trying to avoid Captcha, then one quick suggestion is to use a simple Text trap.

Under your text area, add a question, such as;

> "How many days are in a week?"

Then add another text box, and compare this to say;

> 7 or Seven etc.

If the test fails, then reject the entry...

You may need to vary your question over time, or even have a list of different questions, but this is a simple and easy method to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The answers here are good, but sometimes fooling bots is a good first step.

The vast majority of bots just read the source code and will fill in all the input fields they can find with garbage, send the request, and then hope it worked. They are pretty stupid, so something like this may fool most bots:

```
<p style="display:none">Screen readers: Use the next textarea (the first is used to confuse spam bots).</p>
<textarea name="comment" style="display:none"></textarea>
<textarea name="real_comment"></textarea>
```

And then in your script:

```
if (isset($_POST['comment']) && strlen($_POST['comment']) > 0) {
    die('Bots begone!');
}
$comment = $_POST['real_comment'];
```

In other words, put a dummy `textarea` in the HTML, hide it using CSS, and then wait for bots to fill it in.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way to do what you want is to search for the string `http://`

The following if-statement allows up to 3 links in `$text`

```
if (substr_count($text,"http://") > 3)
```

But that's not really a sufficent check, because there is a lot of spam, which doesn't contain any links at all - just rubish.

So the second you have to do, is a black list with "bad words"

```
    $lower = strtolower($text);
    foreach ($blockword as $word) {
            if (strpos($lower, strtolower($word))>0) {
                    //handle spam here..
            }
    }
```

and after all, you have to maintain a growing list with words and still have to delete a lot of spam..

So you have the option to add an invisible field with random values, which are stored in the session and check if this value is submited correctly

```
$_SESSION["random_secret"] = //create random string..
```

and later check

```
if ($_POST["secret"] == $_SESSION["random_secret"])
```

with this check, you get rid of a lot of automated spam(but still not all)

and so after all you ended up with captchas

Comment: What if the comments are about HTTP protocol? :)

Comment: non programmers don't talk about http protocols ;) ..but if you have a blog about http protocols.. ehm.. bad luck